# Modal resets the counter back to 1

Tags: php, laravel

Not sure how did it reset/s itself even though it's inside the foreach loop. Here's a snippet from  of my blade view:

```
<tbody>
    <?php $counter = 1; ?>
    @foreach ($guidelines as $guideline)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ $guideline->description }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/general-guidelines/{{ $guideline->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button> 
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="/general-guidelines/{{ $guideline->id }}/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <?php $counter++; ?>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Edit works with `/general-guidelines/1/edit`, `/general-guidelines/2/edit`, `/general-guidelines/5/edit`, etc. But `/delete` would always end up at `/1/delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, because you have only one modal (#myModal), and your button always reference to the(#myModal), so that it will always open up the first modal. Try the solution `#myModal{{ $loop->index }}`.

Secondly, You can use $loop->iteration instead of $counter in the foreach loop.

Try this.

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($guidelines as $guideline)
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ $guideline->description }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/general-guidelines/{{ $guideline->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{ $loop->index }}"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button> 
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{ $loop->index }}" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="/general-guidelines/{{ $guideline->id }}/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: So, it's basically passing a value inside the modal. Got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

with for loop, multiple modals are created but for all the modals generated with for loop, you can not use same id 'myModal' . id should be unique.